# Kendo for Angular - Layout Controls not working

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I'm pretty new to Angular and Kendo UI so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what.  I created a test project and would like to lay out a basic shell using some Kendo layout components.  I imported the package

I added the package using `ng add @progress/kendo-angular-layout` and it ran through and said it worked.  I get the right suggestions for Kendo layout components in my IDE (Webstorm) but when it runs I get no layout components.  Here is my code in the app.component.html file:

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<kendo-splitter orientation="horizontal" style="height: 200px">
  <kendo-splitter-pane [collapsible]="true" size="20%"><div class="pane-content"><p>left pane</p></div></kendo-splitter-pane>
  <kendo-splitter-pane><div class="pane-content"><p>Right Pane</p></div></kendo-splitter-pane>
</kendo-splitter>
<kendo-panelbar>
  <kendo-panelbar-item [title]="'test title'"></kendo-panelbar-item>
</kendo-panelbar>
<div>

</div>
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <img width="300" alt="Angular Logo" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAyNTAgMjUwIj4KICAgIDxwYXRoIGZpbGw9IiNERDAwMzEiIGQ9Ik0xMjUgMzBMMzEuOSA2My4ybDE0LjIgMTIzLjFMMTI1IDIzMGw3OC45LTQzLjcgMTQuMi0xMjMuMXoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBmaWxsPSIjQzMwMDJGIiBkPSJNMTI1IDMwdjIyLjItLjFWMjMwbDc4LjktNDMuNyAxNC4yLTEyMy4xTDEyNSAzMHoiIC8+CiAgICA8cGF0aCAgZmlsbD0iI0ZGRkZGRiIgZD0iTTEyNSA1Mi4xTDY2LjggMTgyLjZoMjEuN2wxMS43LTI5LjJoNDkuNGwxMS43IDI5LjJIMTgzTDEyNSA1Mi4xem0xNyA4My4zaC0zNGwxNy00MC45IDE3IDQwLjl6IiAvPgogIDwvc3ZnPg==">
</div>
<h2>Here are some links to help you start: </h2>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/tutorial">Tour of Heroes</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://angular.io/cli">CLI Documentation</a></h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2><a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="https://blog.angular.io/">Angular blog</a></h2>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The bottom part is just the default Angular boilerplate that I haven't removed yet but leaving it in just in case it has some effect for some reason.

The only css I have so far is this in the app component:

```
.pane-content{
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

and this in the main app styles.css file (I did import the font from Google fonts in the index.html):

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
body {
  font-family: 'Martel Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Here is what I see running on Chrome:

[image: Incorrect Layout]

It's layout out like it doesn't use the Kendo controls at all...  I also tried this with the treeview control and it worked just fine based on their examples, but this one doesn't seem to be for some reason.  Anyone know why?

**--EDIT--**

After the comment below I imported into app.module.ts.  Here is the code in that file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {LayoutModule, PanelBarModule, SplitterModule} from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LayoutModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    SplitterModule,
    PanelBarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

That changed the layout only in that I now see 'test title' instead of 'Untitled'.  Closer but still missing something...

Comment: Did you add the modules to your app modules imports array? (I can't see the imgur btw - behind corp firewall)

Comment: hm.  I hadn't, but I just tried it now and it didn't seem to make a difference.  That's in app.module.ts correct?  Updated to put my code from that file in the question...

Comment: Kendo has some [extensive documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/#toc-basic-usage) and StackBlitz examples for their Angular Components. Have you checked and/or tried to re-produce from the examples there?

Comment: Do you see any errors being thrown up in the dev console?

Comment: no errors in the console.  @KhaledShaaban yes I looked at those and was trying to follow them and thought I did but got stuck here...

Comment: Ok apparently it was something with the development server not refreshing or something.  I stopped the server and restarted and now it's working properly.  Not sure why that is but it seems to have fixed it.  I think the imports issue in combination with server restart... @LazyCoder if you make that an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are importing the appropriate modules in your app.module.ts file...

```
...    
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    LayoutModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    SplitterModule,
    PanelBarModule
  ],
...
```

Comment: For me there is issue in this line:-  import {LayoutModule, PanelBarModule, SplitterModule} from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';                                                         Mine kendo-angular-layout doenot shows these modules. Is there any issue in package.

Answer (score 2):

In my previous experience with Kendo, you might also need to import a css theme into your application. Without it, kendo won't style the components the way their website examples do.

Following their StackBlitz [example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/layout/splitter/#toc-basic-usage), I see they link to a stylesheet on the index.html file. When I remove the line below, the splitter component looks similar to your edit. Give it a shot.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@progress/kendo-theme-default@latest/dist/all.css" />
```

You can try running your code or viewing the sample above by clicking the "Open in StackBlitz" link found.

Comment: Good point.  I forgot to mention that I did import their material theme as well so in my case that wasn't the issue but in others that end up here it may be so thanks for pointing it out...